# Change the page_title value for only one page

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to change the page title for my "all products" page but i don't manage to get it work. I want to set the page title for this page only.

Here is my code which I put in the theme.liquid file in the `<title>` tag:

```
{%- if page_title == "Products" -%}
    {% assign page_title = "Paintings" } 
{%- endif -%}
```

Comment: If that's not working for you - the page title is not "Products" or you're placing this code in the wrong place. Can you provide a URL to the page where you're trying to change the title and probably a bit more code from the layout where you apply that snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the default "All products collection", this should work:

```
{%- if collection.handle == 'all' -%}
    {% assign page_title = "Paintings" }
{%- endif -%}
```